# How get sized nested object in Spring data

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I want to get a list of Persons with their addresses. But for any person if he has more than 3 addresses I want the Query to get just 3 addresses and ignore the others.

```
@Entity
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private String id;

@ElementCollection(targetClass = java.util.ArrayList.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Address> Addresses= new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the result set like that, however I feel like it is not a proper way to handle it.

```
@BatchSize(size = 3)
@ElementCollection(targetClass = java.util.ArrayList.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Address> Addresses= new ArrayList<>();
```